# Launching selenium Chrome from Powershell with a target web site that has a redirect for Auth causes the calling program to hang

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using the below PowerShell code, I am trying to open a web page for a SaaS application (sorry I cannot leave the actual URL in this question as it has our company name) . The SaaS app relies on Azure AD SSO for authentication. The target web site loads correctly but disappears after only a split second, as it immediately gets redirected to get authentication. Since the authentication is performed by Azure, the new page that loads is the standard Azure AD login page. Approximately 8 out of 10 times, the Navigate function (last line) hangs as though selenium cannot determine that the original page has loaded successfully, and so processing cannot continue. Effectively, the PS program hangs for 60 seconds until the timeout expires, then throws an error.

Any suggestions?

This is sample code:

```
 $Params = @{
  DefaultDownloadPath = "c:\temp"
  Quiet = $true 
  HideVersionHint = $true 
  DisableAutomationExtension = $true
  Implicitwait= 10
  }
$driver = Start-SeChrome @Params -Arguments @("--remote-allow-origin","--window-size=808,859","--window-position=0,0",'Incognito',"--disable-gpu","--disable-extensions","--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage",'--ignore-certificate-errors',"--disable-infobars")
$Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(https://somewebpage.com)
```

This is the error that pops up after 60 sec:

```
Exception calling "GoToUrl" with "1" argument(s): "The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL 
http://localhost:63454/session/fed050afd83c789dfbdd78a16ff90b61/url timed out after 60 seconds."
At C:\temp\Simpletest2.ps1:14 char:5
+     $Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://somewebpage...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebDriverException
```

Before you suggest it, I have already considered simply calling Azure for SSO first (with the AppID of the desired SaaS app), but this cannot work because the redirect that's supposed to happen adds both a NONCE and STATE parameter (to prevent man-in-the-middle and other such shenanigans), both of which are dynamic. So the  redirect is a required step.